# Why was Goose renamed from Chewie for the Captain Marvel film?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In the new *Captain Marvel* film there is a cat that plays a role in the plot, named Goose.

This character is also present in the comics but is known as Chewie.

Now I don't think it is very hard to see where these names took inspiration from... Chewie from *Star Wars* and Goose from *Top Gun*. Both are a nice fit for Carol's background as a fighter pilot.

But why the change in name? Did it have something to do with the studios and naming rights; Disney owns both Marvel and *Star Wars* now so I don't think that should have been too much of a hassle? Was is that since the film took place between 1989 and 1995 that *Top Gun* was more period relevant in the film? Carol does pick up a copy of *The Right Stuff* in the Blockbuster store (should have been *Top Gun* though).

I am looking for a comment from someone on the production team (e.g. director, writer, studio exec.) for the film as to why the name was changed.

Comment: As a side note I thought the name Goose might foreshadow the fate of the cat, considering Goose's fate in Top Gun. Thankfully, this was not the case.

Comment: Just wait until *Endgame* when we meet Nick Fury's present-day pet, a goose named Flerken.

Comment: I think it was Carol being a fighter pilot that made Goose more relevant. Chewbacca is not a fighter pilot.

Comment: “Carol does pick up a copy of The Right Stuff in the Blockbuster store (should have been Top Gun though)?” Given that *The Right Stuff* is the story of [test pilots, some of whom end up going to space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Right_Stuff_(film)), it seems like an even more apposite reference than *Top Gun*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ah well, yes, you do have I point there.... I was just thinking in terms of the cat's name....

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Goose from Top Gun wasn't a (fighter) pilot either; he was a RIO (Radar Intercept Officer). In the Navy RIOs performed other duties and, in F-14 Tomcats (the aircraft flown in Top Gun), were completely incapable of piloting the aircraft (due to lack of available controls and training). These days RIOs have been replaced by WSOs (Weapon Systems Officers), who *can* control/fly the aircraft if necessary (in F-15s and newer, usually).

Comment: @TylerH Yes, that that is the point, Goose is the Goose to Carol's Maverick.

Comment: @Skooba Paul's comment about using Goose over Chewie due to Chewie not being a fighter pilot implies that Goose *is* one. The point of *my* comment is that that's not correct. A better description of the metaphor would be that they were both "second mates" (to phrase their duties loosely) to famous (and famously skilled) pilots in recent popular culture.

Comment: I think it's a little strange for an Air Force pilot to name her cat after the RIO in what was essentially a propaganda movie for the Navy. Inter-service rivalry and all that. It would have made more sense for her to name it after an Air Force hero like Rickenbacker or Hap. But maybe Carol was above those sort of petty disagreements between services.

Comment: @TylerH true true. I should have said *Han* wasn't a US Air Force fighter pilot.

Comment: @Seneca: if we can trust Carol's jumbled memories, it seems like Doctor Lawson named Goose; who is, at the risk of spoiling the movie for you, not a cat.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: No worries, I just spoiled it for myself. Goose, indeed.

Comment: Here, have a silver badge! :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Anna Boden and Ryan Fleck have answered this during an interview with Collider. In short it appears to have been because they wanted a reference more specific to Danvers' past and something that would line up with her more specifically than *Star Wars*.

> During a recent press day for *Captain Marvel*, I got the chance to sit down with directing duo **Anna Boden** and **Ryan Fleck** and posed that exact question to them. Here’s what Fleck said:
>
> “It wasn’t a big thing. It just felt like *Star Wars* was so part of the culture that, it just felt like we wanted to remove it a little bit, you know, the nostalgia for the *Star Wars* movies which there are so many of around us. You know, when we were kids, *Star Wars* felt like it was something from the 70s and 80s, and I think that was the spirit of Chewie from the comics but we felt like we wanted to sort of just slide away from that slightly.”
>
> Boden further added:
>
> “Yeah, and just the idea of having a reference that would have been so specific to Carol Danvers’ past, as her past in the movie itself being a pilot in the 1980s when *Top Gun* was out and having a reference that felt a little bit more specific to her, whereas Chewie, when the comics were being written was a very specific reference in time but now with all the movies out it feels more contemporary and not so specific to her past.”
>
> <sub>[Collider, ‘Captain Marvel’ Directors Explain Why They Changed the Cat’s Name](https://collider.com/captain-marvel-cat-explained/)</sub>

Comment: This is kind of odd though, yes, the cat is in the film, but _it isn't her cat_.  From all the promotional material, I would have thought it would be the cat she "left behind"

Comment: @Baldrickk FWIW I won't be seeing the film until some time tomorrow so can't really comment on all the ins and outs. I just provided what the directors have said :)

Comment: oh, it's not a detraction of your answer, just pointing out that the cat wasn't connected to her past life at all, so any naming choice is incidental as far as the _story_ is concerned - sorry for very minor spoilers.  Enjoy the movie!

Comment: @Baldrickk: “the cat wasn't connected to her past life at all”. That's not quite true. In one of Carol's flashbacks during the memory extraction process, Goose curls around Carol's legs, causing Doctor Lawson to note that Goose likes her.