# What is the lifespan of a Flerken?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

As we know, cats have a very short lifespan, and *Goose* in *Captain Marvel* looked like an Earth cat but was an alien species(*Flerken*). It lived much longer than a cat. What is the lifespan of a Flerken?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kevin Feige has spoken about this with Slash Film but gives no definite answer only stating that they probably have a longer lifespan than cats.

> **I’m wondering what has Goose been doing for the last 20 years? Can we get like a short film on Disney+ where we would like see that Goose was secretly offscreen at all of these important events?**
>
> I love it! And by the way, that’s one of the fun things about Disney+ is we could actually do ideas like that. The fun thing about introducing new characters and all these movies is suddenly going from a character that maybe you’d heard of if you’d read the books, but if you hadn’t, you’d never heard of him. And then you see the movie, you go, “I want to see more of that character.” And the fact that you and other people are asking, “When do we see more of the cat?” The question is “how long – what is the lifespan of a flerken?” It’s a good question.
>
> **I was just wondering that earlier today because the lifespan of a cat is 15 years, so would Goose be dead?**
>
> But that’s a cat, a flerken might be longer lived. And as we know from the comics, flerken procreate quite a bit. I don’t want to say Tribble-esque, but there’s sort of points in those comics where they sort of are in terms of how many appear. So I’m sure there are more flerken out there. And is Goose out there? She could be.
>
> <sub>[Slash Film, Interview: Kevin Feige Talks ‘Captain Marvel’ Spoilers, The Future of Goose, Stan Lee’s Tribute, and Disney+ TV Shows](https://www.slashfilm.com/kevin-feige-captain-marvel-interview/)</sub>

Samuel L. Jackson has commented on this in [an interview](https://www.fandom.com/video/XH5uLalE/spider-man-far-from-home-cast-answers-your-fan-questions) himself stating that Goose was probably in his office up until at least the start of *Iron Man*. As it is an actor stating this though I’d take it with a pinch of salt.

> **What was Goose doing, where was he, between the end of *Captain Marvel* and the beginning of *Iron Man*?**
>
> He was in my office apparently, there’s all that stuff. Even though we never saw him he was around. I mean we got the, y'know, the thing back somehow. I walked in my office, he'd thrown it up, it was sitting on my desk or whatever so.

As we know Goose was around in 1989 before Mar-Vell’s death and *Iron Man* takes place in 2008 that would make Goose at least 19 but he would be a bit older because Mar-Vell was familiar with him. So flerkens appear to be able to live up to at least 19 years.

Comment: To be fair, while the average lifespan of a cat may be 15 years, it's not totally implausible that one could live to about 20 (our neighbours cat died shortly before her 21st birthday).

Comment: 19 years is actually a longish but fairly normal lifespan for a cat. Roughly equivalent to 80 years for a human. @DoctorPenguin you beat me by one second.

Comment: 19 is just the possible rough age Goose could be but he is most certainly older. There is no indication that Goose is nearing the end of his life.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot in the comics captain marvel had a flerken pet with some other name has it ever been mentioned about its age that it lived upto how many years

Comment: @codeczar It was named Chewie, see [this related Q/A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/207046/58193). I haven't looked to be honest on its age though as this was about the MCU.

Comment: What is the age of Chewie is it very high as compared to a cat

Comment: @DoctorPenguin The oldest recorded domestic cat lived to be... *ahem*... [***thirty eight***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creme_Puff_(cat)). Domestic cats living into their 30s are pretty dang rare (think [supercentenarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercentenarian) humans), but not unheard of.

Comment: @Lexible - I'm always quite dubious when I hear stories about ultra-long lived pets. Is it more likely the that cat lived to be 38 or that at some point they swapped the cat with a younger one

Comment: @Valorum Eh... the distribution of life-spans is skewed sharply to the right in a very long thin tail: *someone* has to be at the upper extremes. What's more likely, that someone has hundreds of billions of dollars, or that they swapped the name of a nation, corporation or bank for Vladimir Putin? ;)

Comment: @lexible - I recently read that the world's oldest woman was likely to actually be her mother and that she swapped in order to commit inheritance fraud

Comment: @Valorum Kitty-cats *do* try and pull inheritance fraud more frequently than horses... ;)

Comment: @lexible - Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof. The idea that a cat could live to the human equivalent of 270+ years isn't beyond the *realms of reality*, but I'd want to see a buttload of proof.

Comment: @Valorum I think you are reifying the concept of "cat years." Enough folks have documented extremely old cats, (and my vet reports having treated cats in their late 20s), that I am satisfied. :) But you do you! Skepticism is healthy. :)